Confused on the way a rocket lifts off

'A rocket lifts off because the exhaust gases exert a force on the rocket'.

However this statement confuses me as I would like more detail. How does it actually work? What are the forces and where do they come from? How could I build an equation to see it more clearly?

This may help: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06042

Getting a bit familiar with the rocket equation and how its derived is a good start. There's an adequate exposition in the given link, but this is also often given in standard mechanics textbooks.

Have you ever blown up a balloon and then let it go? It's exactly the same, except there is a combustion reaction happening to continuously supply new pressurized gas

The force comes from the gas particles, at high pressure, pushing against the walls of the combustion chamber. Newton's 3rd law does not tell you what caused the force on the rocket, but it does enable you to observe that if the rocket produces a force on the gas, then the gas must exert a force on the rocket.

This question is similar to: What is a rocket engine thrusting against in space?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

thank you all, your comments helped me understand :)

Imagine you have cube shaped box filled with pressurised gas. The gas pushes against all the walls. The resulting force from the gas on the box is zero because the forces on opposing walls cancel out.
And now imagine you remove one of the walls but still maintain the pressure inside. Two things will happen: (1) the net force is no longer zero - the gas still pushes against the wall opposite the one you removed but there is no counter acting force. This is where the thrust comes from. (2) the gas rushes out through the opening you made - these are the exhaust gases that exit the rocket engine.
To prevent the pressure inside the box from dropping you have to keep re-supplying the pressurised gas - this is done by injecting fuel and oxidiser into the box (engine) and burning it. You push in relatively small volume of liquid (or gas) at high pressure (you have to push against the pressurised gas that is already in the box). As it burns it expands so you end up with a large volume of pressurised gas in the chamber such that the pressure inside does not drop despite the large flow out.

thank you so much! does the thrust come from Newton's 3rd Law? or from somewhere else?

Yes, you can see it that way too. The gas is pushed down out of the rocket (action) so in turn it must push the rocket up (reaction).

Basic principle is simple, it works because of action-reaction force pair, like here in the picture,

You throw boxes out of car with force,
$$ \tag 1 F_{\text{thrust}} = \dot m v_e, $$
where $v_e$ is exhaust velocity and $\dot m$ is car mass change over time in $[kg/s]$ and same force exhaust applies to your car due to Third Newton law. By analogy $\dot m$ measures how much such people you have standing on a trolley. The more you have,- the more boxes they can throw out per time unit,- each with momentum $m_{box}v_e$ and as such total force passed back to trolley scales-up linearly. But core rocket moving principle is as primitive as gun recoil.
The difference being is that in rocket case we favor recoil and try to maximize it by any means, for example by choosing favorable nozzle which accelerates gas flow, since full rocket thrust equation is,
$$ \tag 2 F_{rocket} = \dot m v_e + \Delta pA_e ,$$
where $\Delta p $ is pressure difference between nozzle input and output, and $A_e$- nozzle exit cross-section. So, in conclusion you can call rocket "a maximized recoil system."

In this example the force on the trolley is entirely from the man's feet. In order to explain  how this relates to $\dot{m} v_e$ you need to provide some more explanation.

I don't see why force from feet is different than a force from exhaust gas projected into some rocket base cross-section ? It relates to mass change in this way,- the greater rate of throwing boxes is,- the faster you accumulate car momentum change per unit time period. So to say "power" of such engine increases. You can fill your new answer as well,- maybe you will explain things not mentioned by me better.

Thrown away box pushes man backwards and because he is part of trolley system due to static friction of his feets with ground,- trolley is pushed backwards too. So force on trolley is only due to third Newton law, due to which box passes back force to trolley-man system. You can replace man on trolley with let's say some sort of "gun"  which is mounted on trolley and fires boxes constantly. Same effect will happen, which btw is called "gun's recoil". $\dot m$ is just a measure of how much such guns you have mounted on top of car.
